# ¿Cómo leer los datos de un csv y guardarlos en un diccionario?

Tags: python, csv, diccionarios

Tengo un archivo .csv con varias filas, y quiero crear una función para leerlo en un diccionario, de manera que al final obtenga una estructura en la que los tres primeros elementos de cada fila sean la clave (como una tupla) , y el cuarto elemento el valor. Hasta ahora he llegado aquí:

```
import csv

def cargar_datos(archivo_csv):
    diccionario = dict({})
    with open(archivo_csv, 'r') as tabla:
        lineas = csv.reader(tabla, delimiter=';')
        cabecera = next(lineas)
        lineas_sel = list(lineas)
        for l in lineas_sel:
            diccionario[(lineas_sel[0], lineas_sel[1], lineas_sel[2])] = lineas_sel[3]
        return diccionario
```

Me salta el siguiente  error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.
¿Qué puedo hacer?

Gracias por la ayuda y un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando listas dentro de las claves del diccionario.
El motivo es un *typo* o error de escritura en tu código:

Corregir la línea dentro del `for` a:

```
diccionario[(l[0], l[1], l[2])] = l[3]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias aeportugal! Sí, efectivamente era un error de escritura, pero al modificarlo sigo sin obtener el resultado deseado. Si leo, por ejemplo, un csv de 10 filas, únicamente almacena en la memoria del diccionario la última de estas, obteniendo un diccionario de una única clave y un único valor. Gracias por tu tiempo y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Además de lo que ya te ha dicho aeportugal sobre tu error, puedes simplificar tu código.

Puedes crear directamente el diccionario desde el `csv.reader`:

```
def cargar_datos(archivo_csv):
    with open(archivo_csv, 'r') as tabla:
        return {tuple(k):v for *k, v in csv.reader(tabla, delimiter=';')}
```

Comment: Millones de gracias! Esta forma es muchísimo más elegante y simple!